# Deploying the app on android device

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a situation, I don't have any usb cable to connect my device with my system to deploy my android app from eclipse and my device is not rooted so I can't use wifi adb for deployment, Is there any fastest way to deploy on device ?? please suggest

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can export the application to your computer and email it to yourself then install it from the email. or you can go to the store and buy a cable for really cheap

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but actually I want to deploy directly from eclipse, Using this approach it takes time to install on device and in this situation I am unable to get a cable.

Answer (score 2):

Step #1: Upload the APK to the Internet (e.g., Dropbox)

Step #2: Download the APK from the Internet to the device (e.g., via Dropbox app)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have an apk. So you can send it to an e-mail address. Then open that mail from device and download the attached apk. After download is finished install the apk by clicking on it.

Remember to enable `Unknown sources` under `Settings / Security`.